# How to test the code with rethrowing exceptions?

Tags: java, android, testing, exception

I have a piece of code in my android app that catches one exception and rethrows it as another, custom exception extended from `RuntimeException`. And it seems impossible to be tested.

Take a look at the following code:

```
 try { ... } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     throw new CustomMalformedDataException(downloadUrlString, e);
 }
```

When I try to test the exception case, I write:

```
@Test(expected = CustomMalformedDataException.class)
public void exceptionsTest() throws Exception {
    <code triggering the exception>
}
```

But i get **`Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.net.MalformedURLException'`**

When I write:

```
@Test(expected = MalformedURLException.class)
public void exceptionsTest() throws Exception {
    <code triggering the exception>
}
```

I get **`java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<java.net.MalformedURLException> but was<CustomMalformedDataException>`**

So how should I test this case?

Code of exception class:

```
public class CustomMalformedDataException extends RuntimeException {

    public CustomMalformedDataException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public CustomMalformedDataException(String url, MalformedURLException cause) {
        super("The package has an invalid \"downloadUrl\": " + url, cause);
    } 
}
```

UPDATE: It seems that either way tests stop execution at the point where the initial exception is thrown, even though it is caught. But in case this exception is *expected*, the execution continues and throws another exception, which is already *not expected*.

Comment: what's you junit version?

Comment: I use 4.12 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried out your code and got a different error so I can't give you an answer, but I've got a way of testing errors I prefer using JUnit that will get you the results you need

```
@Rule
public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testExceptionOccurs() throws Exception {
    exception.expect(CustomMalformedDataException.class);
    //code that casues exception to happen
}
```

I've run this plenty of times and it works with no issues when I need to test that my exceptions are occuring. I hope this at least helps giving you a solution to writing exception tests.

If you really need to test `RuntimeException` then have your test throw `RuntimeException` instead of `Exception`

Comment: This is better, but now I get `Expected: an instance of CustomMalformedDataException
but: <java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: CustomMalformedDataException> is a java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException `

Comment: So this code should work as it stands. Without seeing more of your code base it's hard to say what the issue could be. From the error it looks like youre passing on some instance of ExecutionException that is a CustomMalformedDataException, so it would be good to see how you construct your exception.

Comment: I've added the code to the post. That could be right, because Custom exception is extended from Runtime exception

Comment: Ah, so thats the problem. You shouldn't be extending from `RuntimeException` but just from `Exception`. 

If you read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) you'll see it says "...the Java programming language does not require methods to catch or to specify unchecked exceptions (RuntimeException, Error, and their subclasses)"

Comment: So is this correct that no way I can test cases with Runtime exceptions?

Comment: If so, modify your answer so I can accept or I will add mine

Comment: A `RuntimeException` is supposed to represent a programming problem , so it isn't expected for your application to be able to recover from them or handle them in any way. If you're expecting to recover from your `Exception`, then it should be a checked exception. But if you are expecting the app to be unable to recover then an unchecked exception is suitable.